# RS-232 returning question marks when reading serial port

Tags: serial, rs232

I have a question about receiving responses from a machine using PySerial's `read` method.

I am new to this forum as a chemistry student with minimal experience with the RS-232 protocol and intermediate Python skills, so I apologise for any errors in the body of the question although I'm happy to do any extended reading where possible.

I am currently working on automating a Flow Chemistry machine that uses a RJ12 6P6C to RS-232C connection using a Raspberry Pi 400. The machine is configured using the following settings:

- 9600 Baud
- 8 data bits
- 1 stop bit
- No parity

I'm using an Ohaus interface kit ([Item 30304101](https://www.coleparmer.co.uk/i/ohaus-30304101-interface-kit-rs-232-to-usb/1100374)) for the RS-232 to USB conversion, which is plugged into the Raspberry Pi that I'm using.

I've written the following function to monitor the response byte from the machine, which prints each bit individually for analysis:

```
def monitor(ser):
    
for i in range(10):
    resp_raw = ser.read(1)

    print(resp_raw)
```

Where `ser` is the serial connection provided by the following line:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, timeout=0.1)
```

I then run the following block of code on Jupyter Notebook to check the current conditions (hence 'CC') with a carriage return as requested by the machine specifications:

> Optionally, a carriage return may be used to indicate the end of a transmitted string.
> A received carriage return will cause the Flow Machine to immediately respond to the
> received command and may help speed communications.

```
command_string = 'CC'+chr(13)

ser.write(command_string.encode())

response = monitor(ser)
```

When I send over the command `CC`, I expect the following response in the output of the Jupyter cell:

```
b'O'
b'K'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

to signify the word 'OK'.

However, I seem to be getting a question mark i.e. `?` continuously, followed by a carriage return – this is not what I am expecting as I mentioned above:

```
b'?'
b'\r'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

So far, I've seen suggestions that the `?` signifies an [unrepresentable character](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1088792/Serialport-retrieving-QUESTION-MARKS), or that the serial setup with the baud rate and so on are [incorrect](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b354b10-31bc-47a1-b52c-7cd9d55e1bd3/incorrect-data-received-thourgh-serialport?forum=csharpgeneral), but neither of these suggestions match what I am observing – the setup of the serial port matches the description given by the machine manual, and I am using Python's `print()` method to print out the received bytes:

> The RS-232 REMOTE INPUT serial communications port is configured by default for
> 9600 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and no parity. The connector is a standard RJ12
> modular telephone type jack.

What is the possible reason for the `?` that I am receiving when I am reading in the bytes from the RS-232 serial port connection?

Comment: You forgot to mention what kind of USB to serial adapter you have - please mention exact make and model as it is important.

Comment: Hi, @Justme – I've updated the body of the question to include the Ohaus RS-232 to USB Interface Kit that I'm using to connect to the Pi – I hope this is what you required!

Comment: Some points: 1) "configured **by default**" - dig through the machine's menu and verify that it hasn't been changed 2) just for testing increase the timeout - you'd be surprised, but 100ms might be short if your Pi lags anywhere 3) why not test from a PC for a start? Then just move your code to the Pi? seems easier to do it that way if you're using a USB-serial adapter anyway.

Comment: @vik1245 Let's assume you have the rate specified correctly for a moment. Then you are actually getting a ? followed by a CR (carriage return) if I'm reading the meaning of \r correctly. That might be a valid response to a command it doesn't understand. Yes?

Comment: Try wiring up a loopback to confirm that you're sending what you think you are. Then once you're sure of that double check the configuration of the instrument and it's manual to make sure what you've sent is correct. Also try throwing some other commands at it to see what happens. You might also try calling the lab instrument manufacturer. One advantage of (presumably) extremely expensive products that the manufacturer will usually answer the phone, and more often than not put you on the line with someone helpful.

Comment: as it's saying `b'?'` it's actually a question mark coming back.  unprintable would look different.